# web API unit test not working as expected

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

I am new to Web API. I have inherited code with unit tests written in c#. However, when I run unit tests the tests pass irrespective of the controller name. For ex: http://localhost/api/users -> even if users is misspelled the unit test passes.

I have the following code in the controller:

```
public async Task TestGetUsers()
{
    usersController controller = new usersController(new TestUserRepository());
    ApiControllerConfig.SetupControllerForTest(controller, "http://localhost/api/users", HttpMethod.Get);
    IHttpActionResult result = controller.Get();
    HttpResponseMessage message = await result.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken.None);
    string content = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Assert.IsTrue(content.Length > 0);
}
```

Not sure if this information is sufficient to tell me where the problem lies but please let me know if more information needs to be posted.

Comment: What unit test framework are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You're reading the content from a 404 not found request: that will still have content (to tell you the content could not be found). Therefore asserting that the content length is over 0 makes no sense because it doesn't differentiate between a failed and a passed test.

What you should do is look at the statuscode (`message.StatusCode`) and make sure that is `HttpStatusCode.Ok`.

I would also advice to just add the Web Api project as a reference to your unit test project -- that way you can call the methods directly rather than having to go through a `HttpClient`. For more on this (including testing your routes), take a look at [my blog](http://www.vannevel.net/2015/03/08/50/).

Answer (score -1):

you could use directly the apicontroller in the test project, just add the reference and test it.

Something like this:

```
 public void TestMethod()
    {
       var ctr = new MyApiController();
       string name = ctr.GetName();
       Assert.IsTrue(name == "xpto");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Coastpear for responding. Is that the only way to make it work?